# Zabbix Active Agent

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I set up a Zabbix-Server and installed on some other Servers the Zabbix-Agent.
Now I want to add some items which require `Zabbix Agent(Active)`.

So I configured my agents, set `ServerActive` to my Zabbix-Server-IP, added my `Hostname` and `Server` in my `zabbix_agentd.conf`.

But when I try to test a item with

```
zabbix_agent -t log[/tmp/asdf.log]
```

Zabbix tells me `Accessible only as active check`.
So I think that I missed to configure something.

My Zabbix-Agent version is `Zabbix agent v2.4.7`

Answer (score 4):

The log monitoring items, `log[]` and `logrt[]`, are only accessible as active checks (just like the error message says), meaning that they cannot be accessed using `zabbix_get` or processed using the `-t` option, so there is no error in your setup. You should simply make the agent obtain that `log[]` item as an active check from Zabbix server and verify whether it works that way.

Also, see official Zabbix documentation for more information on [log monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items) and the difference between [passive and active checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/items/activepassive).